# Quicksight data import/upload skipping Empty DATE even though i gave 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Am uploading an CSV to quicksight
Eq data:

```
id     Name        Date
1      ABCD        2021-06-10 00:12:00
2      QAZX        0000-00-00 00:00:00 ----> This row don't have Date, so filled dummy date as specified in quicksight troubleshooting
```

The rows with default date format are being skipped.
any inputs will solve my issue are appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter on your visual representation. The filter should be applied to your "Date" column with the following properties:

- Drop down 1: Date & time Range
- Drop down 2: After
- Time granularity: Day
- Date: 1000-01-01

Visually, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This is not after importing data , this is during import. Quicksight is not importing whole data , columns with no date are skipped even default date is added as mentioned above

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I confirm that I encountered the same problem. A workaround consists in letting empty the field Date for the rows with no dates. For example, the following works fine: 
`id,Name,Date
1,ABCD,"10/06/2021 00:12:00"
2,QAZX,""`